# Tkinter code runs fine from spyder but when converted to .exc doesn't open (python)

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, executable

I have some code that is meant to take a the path to a folder of data files, extract and tidy the data, then return a single pandas dataframe that can be saved. To make it more user friendly I have added a user interface with tkinter. It all runs fine in spyder, and making the executable with pyinstaller seems to run ok, but when I try to run the .exc it simply opens the blank command window without opening the UI. It doesn't give any errors so I don't know where to start on the debugging, any help gratefully received.

My code consists of four files:

**tidyEPR.py** (a single function that opens and cleans up a single epr file. Packages:*Pandas*)

**rowNames.csv** (contains variable names.)

**combEPRs.py** (a single function that iterates through data files and calls tidyEPR() to combine data into a single dataframe and opens rowNames.csv to rename the rows. Packages:*Pandas, pathlib, glob*)

**practice.py** (a tkinter application that allows the user to input data and save locations and press a button to  run, calls combEPRs. Packages: *Tkinter, os, sys*)

To make the .exc I put all the above into one folder, then use

> pyinstaller --onefile practice.py

or

> pyinstaller practice.py

in cmd, in both cases it appears to run successfully and makes the .exc file.

No errors are raised. I have tried converting a different tkinter script with the above method and it works fine so it is definitely something wrong with my code.

I have never tried to do this kind of thing before so my code may be a bit of a mess, sorry.

Here is practice.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
import sys
#import custom functions
from combEPRs import combEPRs


#set working directory to file location
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))

window = tk.Tk()

#initilaise df
df="empty"

def makeFile():
    global df
    #retrive entered text
    enteredText = ent_dataPath.get()
    #create dataframe from data files in entred path
    df = combEPRs(enteredText)
    #update label to show the finished dataframe
    lbl_ConsoleReadout.config(text=df)

def saveFile():
    global df
    #change label to say "saving..."
    lbl_ConsoleReadout.config(text="saving...")
    #retrive entered text
    enteredText = ent_savePath.get()
    #save dataframe
    df.to_csv(enteredText)
    #change label text to say "Done!"
    lbl_ConsoleReadout.config(text="Done!")

frame = tk.Frame(borderwidth=5)
frame.pack()

#make label to explain what to do
lbl_info = tk.Label(
    text="Put full path to the data folder then press go, if you are hapy with output put in full save path and press save", 
    master = frame,
)
lbl_info.pack(pady=10)

#make text entry widget to get path to data folder
ent_dataPath = tk.Entry(
    master = frame,
    width = 100
)
ent_dataPath.pack(pady=10)

#make button to press to submit folder to combEPRs
btn_go = tk.Button(
    text="GO",
    width = 10,
    height = 2,
    master = frame,
    command = makeFile
)
btn_go.pack(pady=10)

#make text widget to print output to.
lbl_ConsoleReadout = tk.Label(
    width = 100
)
lbl_ConsoleReadout.pack()

#make text entry widget to get path to to save to
ent_savePath = tk.Entry(
    master = frame,
    width = 100
)
ent_savePath.pack(pady=10)

#make save button
btn_save = tk.Button(
    text="SAVE",
    width = 10,
    height = 2,
    master = frame,
    command = saveFile
)
btn_save.pack(pady=10)

window.mainloop()
```